# Why Did Tim Burton cut the Ballad from Sweeney Todd?

Tags: musical, play-adaptation, sweeney-todd

So, I've been thinking a lot about Tim Burton's movie adaptation of Stephen Sondheim's stage musical, *Sweeney Todd*. (Or, rather, I was recently reminded of a question that I had when it first came out, and that was never quite answered to my satisfaction.)

So... personally, I was always disappointed that they chose not to include *any* of the **lyrics** from the "Ballad of Sweeney Todd" (the opening number or any of its reprises). I kinda got why they wouldn't want it to be a chorus number, since they cut out or changed most of the libretto that required a chorus (I believe that there's an interview somewhere out there in which Tim Burton talks about how that was a conscious decision). And there were some lyrics in the "Ballad" that wouldn't quite have fit for a movie (e.g. "What happened then, well that's the play/and he wouldn't want us to give it away"). But for other songs - e.g. "God, That's Good" - they found ways to keep at least part of the song's lyrics, but just cut out the chorus or otherwise alter the song to make it fit for a chorus-less movie rather than a chorus-ful (so to speak) stage musical.

And in other movies based on stage musicals, switching up lyrics so that they're more suitable for the medium (and sometimes for much less apparent reasons, but that's beside the point) seems to be the norm. The first example I can think of is *Rent,* which went through quite a lot of minor changes in its script and lyrics when it was adapted for the screen. For example, part of Collins' solo introducing Angel in the song "Today 4 U" was changed from "Gentlemen, our benefactor on this Christmas Eve/whose charity is only matched by talent, I believe" in the stage version to "Gentlemen, our benefactor on this Christmas Day/whose charity is only matched by talent, I must say" in the movie. (There are quite a few other examples, but you get the idea.)

So, as a musical theater nerd, I can't help but wonder (even with my personal disappointment aside), **why did Tim Burton and co. decide to *completely* cut the lyrics from such an iconic song as "The Ballad of Sweeney Todd" instead of just altering it? Was there a particular reason, or was it just a (relatively) "random" casualty of the song-slashing that always seems to happen when stage musicals are adapted for the screen?** (Maybe the Ballad isn't as iconic as I always thought it to be?)

Answer (score 1):

Burton felt that the ballad (and most of the other song that required a chorus) were simply too '*theatrical*'. He strongly wanted to preserve the songs *where one individual is singing to another on screen* and lose the ones where background characters and choral singers need to join in with them.

> **Q:** **What role do you think the music plays in Sweeney Todd, which is strong enough as a stand alone story?**
>
> **Burton:** *One of the things I loved about the musical was that you listened to the soundtrack and it told you the story. **We didn't want it to be what I'd say was a traditional musical with a lot of dialogue and then singing. It felt like a silent movie with singing. That's why we cut out a lot of choruses and things, and extras singing and dancing down the street.** Each of the characters, because a lot of them are repressed and have their emotions inside, the music was a way to let them express their feelings. That was the structure we used for it. When I first saw the show the imagery, which is quite dark and harsh, set with the music, which is quite lush and beautiful, was something I'd never seen before and was the reason I wanted to do it.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The cast of Sweeney Todd reveal all...](https://www.basingstokegazette.co.uk/leisure/general/1984105.the-cast-of-sweeney-todd-reveal-all/)</sup></sub>

He felt that *The Ballad of Sweeney Todd* was entirely superfluous.

> Burton didn’t want patches of dialogue interrupted by song, as is
> traditional. He cut the show’s famous opening number, “The Ballad of
> Sweeney Todd.” *Why have a chorus singing about “attending the tale of
> Sweeney Todd” when you could just go ahead and attend it?*
>
> <sub><sup>[LA Times - Tim Burton’s slasher movie](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2007-nov-25-ca-burton25-story.html)</sup></sub>

---

It may interest you to learn that early drafts of the script did have the chorus parts and the studio even went as far casting and announcing Christopher Lee, Peter Bowles and Anthony Stuart Head as "Ghosts" (hired to sing the chorus as Sweeney's victims) before they got the metaphorical chop before filming had begun.

> The new "Gentleman Ghost" character raised many inquisitive eyebrows when Tim Burton's film cast was announced, since the stage musical does not employ such a character. Lee, speaking to London's Telegraph who broke the story, saw the bright side: "It would have been worse if I had done the scenes, but I never got to film them. It's a shame as the lyrics were wonderful, but these things happen."
>
> <sub><sup>[Playbill - Cut: Christopher Lee and Ghosts are Nixed from "Sweeney Todd" Film](https://www.playbill.com/article/cut-christopher-lee-and-ghosts-are-nixed-from-sweeney-todd-film-com-140979)</sup></sub>

A (cover?) story was written that Depp's daughter was unwell to explain why they'd decided not to remove these scenes from the shooting schedule.

> Even by the standards of the Demon Barber, it seems an unkind cut. The
> actor had been looking forward to making his fourth film with Burton
> as director and Johnny Depp as the star, but, at the eleventh hour,
> the character of the Gentleman Ghost that Lee had been signed to play
> was axed. Half a dozen other actors who were due to play singing
> ghosts in the film - including Peter Bowles - are also out. "It was a
> tight production schedule, so, when Johnny had to absent himself when
> his daughter Lily-Rose was taken ill, some scenes had to be cut,"
> explains my man with the clapperboard.
>
> <sub><sup>[Telegraph: A ghost is exorcised](https://web.archive.org/web/20071005153302/http://www.telegraph.co.uk/opinion/main.jhtml?xml=%2Fopinion%2F2007%2F05%2F13%2Fdp1301.xml#head7:%7E:text=Back%20to%20top-,A%20ghost%20is%20exorcised,-Christopher%20Lee%2C%20whose)</sup></sub>